# VueJS - Dynamically filter items inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-for

Given the following template:

```
<template>
  <v-list dark class="ap-sidebar-applist">
    <v-list-group
      ref="topLevelItems"
      class="ap-sidebar-group"
      v-for="(item, i) in visibleItems"
      :key="i"
      :prepend-icon="item.icon"
      :value="item.visible"
      @click="onClick(item)"
    >
      <v-list-tile slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
      <div v-if="item.children">
        <v-list-tile class="sub-list"
          v-for="(subMenu, j) in item.children"
          :key="j"
          @click="onClick(subMenu, true)"
          :class="subMenu.isActive?'v-list__group__header--active':''"
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ subMenu.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ subMenu.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </div>
    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

and the following data

```
export default {
  name: 'TheLeftSidebarAppList',
  props: {
    visible: Boolean,
  },
  data: () => ({
    activeChild: null,
    items: [
      {
        icon: 'group',
        title: 'Users',
        routeTo: 'UserEdit',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        tmCanView: true,
        visible: true,
        children: [
          {
            icon: 'send',
            title: 'Send Quick Alert',
            method: 1,
            isActive: false,
            superOnly: false,
            taCanView: true,
            tmCanView: true,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        icon: 'domain',
        title: 'Tenants',
        routeTo: 'TenantEdit',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        tmCanView: true,
        visible: false,
        children: [
          {
            icon: 'fingerprint',
            title: 'Manage Biometrics',
            routeTo: 'TenantBiometricEdit',
            method: 1,
            isActive: false,
            superOnly: false,
            taCanView: false,
            tmCanView: true,
          },
          {
            icon: 'email',
            title: 'Manage Templates',
            routeTo: 'TenantTemplateEdit',
            method: 1,
            isActive: false,
            superOnly: false,
            taCanView: false,
            tmCanView: true,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        icon: 'assessment',
        title: 'Reports',
        routeTo: 'WorkspaceReports',
        method: null,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: true,
        tmCanView: true,
        visible: false,
      },
      {
        icon: 'settings',
        title: 'Server Configuration',
        routeTo: null,
        method: 2,
        superOnly: false,
        taCanView: false,
        tmCanView: true,
        visible: false,
      },
      {
        icon: 'trending_up',
        title: 'Performance',
        routeTo: 'WorkspacePerformance',
        method: null,
        superOnly: true,
        visible: false,
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('app', {
      myRole: 'getTopRole',
      stickyTenant: 'getStickyTenant',
    }),
    visibleItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => this.isVisible(item));
    },
  },
  methods: {
    isVisible(item) {
      let ret = true;
      if (item.superOnly && this.myRole.roleCode !== 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') {
        ret = false;
      }
      if (!item.taCanView && this.myRole.roleCode === 'ROLE_TENANT_ADMIN') 
      {
        ret = false;
      }
      if (!item.tmCanView && this.myRole.roleCode === 'ROLE_TENANT_MAINT') 
      {
        ret = false;
      }
      return ret;
    },
  },
```

I need to filter out the children elements of the top level `Tenant` menu item by running it through `isVisible()`. My first thought was to use a computed property, but since you can't pass an argument to a computed property, I can't dynamically pass the parent item to get the list of child items and filter them. My other thought was to create a computed property that has the already filtered `Tenant` children items, but then, again because you can't pass an argument to a computed property, I don't have a way of knowing when the `Tenant` menu is being rendered.

How can I dynamically filter the child menu items as needed?

Comment: Create a ListItem component that is dedicated to render child items. One level down you should not have that "passing an argument to computed property" problem.

Comment: When filtering an array that is used by `v-for` you should use a unique key (not the index). Filtering will shuffle the indicies of the items and thus make the VDOM diffing useless for that list.

Comment: So in this case, would using the `icon` key work for the unique key?

Comment: Well is the icon key **unique**?

Comment: Could you please provide a codesandbox or something like that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-j55nr
Does this meet your goal?

Comment: In regards to the filtering functionality, I see what you're doing, and that's the correct idea. there are other things going on in terms of class assignment and other things that I have to figure out, but this is a good starting point. Thanks.

Comment: @wonder95 - given the effort Reijo went to, might be nice to suggest an answer submission and accept if it helped put you on track.